# Play 2.5: Process respones from API

Tags: java, playframework-2.5

I try to call some REST API and process the JSON response, reading the official Play doc, I try this one:

```
CompletionStage<JsonNode> token = ws.url("http://url.com")
    .get()
    .thenApply(response -> response.asJson());
```

But when I print the token using `System.out.println(token)` ,

I got this message `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@4a5ece42[Not completed]` instead of JSON.

I'm still trying to understand the concept of Future and Promise, is there anything that I missed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break this down, you'll find the following:

```
CompletionStage<WSResponse> eventualResponse = ws.url("http://url.com").get()
```

Notice the name I gave the variable: `eventualResponse`.  What is obtained from `.get()` is not a reply from  the HTTP call, but a *promise* that there will eventually be one.

Taking the next step, we have this:

```
CompletionStage<JsonNode> eventualJson = eventualResponse.thenApply(response -> response.asJson());
```

Again, it's a *promise* that when `eventualResponse` is complete and `response` (the lambda parameter) is available, the `asJson` method will be invoked on `response`.  This also happens asynchronously.

That means that what you're passing to `System.out.println` is not the JSON, but rather the promise of JSON.  Accordingly, you're getting the `toString` signature of a `CompletableFuture` (which is an implementation of `CompletionStage`).

To process the JSON, keep the chain going:

```
ws.url("http://url.com")
  .get()
  .thenApply(response -> response.asJson())
  .thenApply(json -> do something with the JSON)
  . and so on
```

**NB** There is a slight difference between a promise and a future - in this answer I've used the terms interchangably, but it's worth knowing the difference.  Take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/207153 for a succinct take on this.

Comment: Thanks! For the answer and the reference, that wikipedia article really give the tick.